# Is this statement about an element in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ correct?

Tags: cyclic-groups, quotient-spaces

I have the following question.

> We have $l\geq 1$ an integer and we consider the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z},\times)$. Given $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we write $[n]=n+l\mathbb{Z}$ for the class of n. We have also a composition law given as $$[m]\times [n]=[m\times n]:=[mn]$$

Now in a subexercise I need to prove a certain statement. I somewhere used that $[ly]=[0]$ for some $y\in \mathbb{Z}$. But I'm not sure if this is correct. I wanted to prove this claim saying that $ly-0\in l\mathbb{Z}$ but is this enough to say that $$[ly]=[0]$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not only is $ly - 0 \in l\mathbb{Z}$ sufficient to conclude that $[ly] = [0]$ in $\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$, it is also *necessary*. If $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a normal subgroup, then two elements $g, g' \in G$ represent the same class in the quotient $G/H$ if and only if $g(g')^{-1} \in H$. This is exactly what you've written with $G = \mathbb{Z}, H = l\mathbb{Z}, g = ly, g' = 0$ (in additive notation, of course).

Comment: ah okei so we do the same as in a general quotient by subgroups and only use the additive notation. I.e. in general we write it with a multiplicatiove notation but in $\mathbb{Z}$ one the additive makes sence right?

Comment: Yep, that's right: in additive notation, instead of $g^{-1}$, we write $-g$.

Comment: perfect thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By definition,
$$
[0]=0+l\mathbb{Z}=l\mathbb{Z}=ly+l\mathbb{Z}=[ly]\ .
$$

Comment: perfect thanks!